# Exporting From Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-text, vba

I have an Excel Sheet with 55 Columns Of Data, Each with 1000 Rows.

Is there any way I can export this from Excel to Notepad in the order of All of Column A, Followed by All Of Column B and so on until it reaches the final column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just save the excel sheet in CSV format, and then open the CSV with Notepad?

Save as CSV:

`File -> Save As` and select CSV from the drop down extension list.

Browse to where you saved the CSV file and right click it -> `Open With` -> `Notepad`

Comment: That would not be "in the order of All of Column A, Followed by All Of Column B and so on until it reaches the final column"